# How do I have more columns than data points in a jqplot barchart and have the trendline continue over all columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

In `jqPlot`, I define an array with the data series and an array with the tick/column labels.  If I have more ticks/columns than data points in the series and have trendline turned on, the trendline only continues over the domain of the data points, not over all columns. **Is there any way to allow the trendline to continue and extrapolate over the whole domain?**

For instance, if I try this data with these ticks:

```
var s1 = [40, 50, 55, 57, 64];
var ticks = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
```

The bars display a little funky, but the trendline is correct, but only for the 5 data points. Alternately, this data with the same ticks:

```
var s1 = [40, 50, 55, 57, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

Has a trendline that nose-dives, which doesn't really describe the trend of the data before the 0's.  Nulls or undefined don't seem to work (instead of 0's) for the remaining columns either.

So, **what do I need to do to show partial data across the domain (the year) and still get an accurate trend/extrapolation line?**

Comment: I don't think jqPlot can do that for you. I think you need to take the data and extrapolate some predictions yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Pass null to it or an empty value [1,2,3... AFAIK